# How to reorder a factor by only a subset of another vector using fct_reorder()?

Tags: r, forcats

Consider the `gss_cat` dataset from the `forcats` package.

I want to create a filled barplot that should ultimately look like this:

[image]

Notice that I ordered `marital` by the proportion of "`Other`" in the `race` variable.

My workaround of this problem, which creates the above plot, looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

forcats::gss_cat %>% 
  group_by(marital) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(race == "Other" ~ mean(race == "Other"),
                         TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(marital = fct_reorder(marital, new_var, max)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(marital, fill = race)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  coord_flip()
```

Basically, I ordererd `marital` using an intermediate varibale `new_var`.

**My Question:**

Is there an easier way to change the order of the factor levels of `marital` depending on the proportion of "`Other`" of the `race` variable, without having to use the intermediate steps `group_by/mutate/ungroup`?

Can I do those steps inside the `fct_reorder` function by telling it to only use max values of a specific subset of `race` (where `race == "Other"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could reduce the couple of steps by using `ave` on the `mutate` step

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
gss_cat %>% 
    mutate(marital = fct_reorder(marital, ave(race == "Other", marital), max)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(marital, fill = race)) +
     geom_bar(position = "fill") +
     coord_flip()
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option is `arrange` and `fct_inorder`

```
gss_cat %>% 
   arrange(ave(race == "Other", marital)) %>%
   mutate(marital = fct_inorder(marital)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(marital, fill = race)) +
     geom_bar(position = "fill") +
     coord_flip()
```